# Javascript Proxy set() local property on inherited objects

Tags: javascript, inheritance, es6-proxy

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/set), 
`handler.set()` can trap Inherited property assignment:

```
Object.create(proxy)[foo] = bar;
```

In which case, how does one both monitor and allow local assignments on inherited objects?

```js
var base = {
 foo: function(){
  return "foo";
 }
}

var proxy = new Proxy(base, {
 set: function(target, property, value, receiver){
  console.log("called: " + property + " = " + value, "on", receiver);
  //receiver[property] = value; //Infinite loop!?!?!?!?!
  //target[property] = value // This is incorrect -> it will set the property on base.
  
  /*
   Fill in code here.
  */
  return true;
 }
})

var inherited = {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(inherited, Object.create(proxy));

inherited.bar = function(){
 return "bar";
}

//Test cases
console.log(base.foo); //function foo
console.log(base.bar); //undefined
console.log(inherited.hasOwnProperty("bar")) //true
```

Answer (score 6):

After some additional thought, i noticed that it intercepts 3 ops:

> Property assignment: proxy[foo] = bar and proxy.foo = bar 
>   Inherited property assignment: Object.create(proxy)[foo] = bar
>   Reflect.set()

but not [`Object.defineProperty()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) which appears to be even lower level than the = operator.

Thus the following works:

```js
var base = {
    foo: function(){
        return "foo";
    }
};

var proxy = new Proxy(base, {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver){
        var p = Object.getPrototypeOf(receiver);
      
        Object.defineProperty(receiver, property, { value: value });   // ***
        return true;
    }
});

var inherited = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(inherited, Object.create(proxy));

inherited.bar = function(){
    return "bar";
};

// Test cases
console.log(base.foo);                       // function foo
console.log(base.bar);                       // undefined
console.log(inherited.bar);                  // function bar
console.log(inherited.hasOwnProperty("bar")) // true
```

Comment: Why didn't I think of that?! :-) You probably want `writable: true, enumerable: true, configurable: true` in there, to make it equivalent.

Comment: That comment of yours just helped me find a bug. Didn't know that enumerable (and all other properties) is false by default X.X

Answer (score 1):

I see two options (maybe):

1. Store the property in a `Map`, keeping the `Map`s for various receivers in a `WeakMap` keyed by the receiver. Satisfy `get` by checking the `Map` and returning the mapping there instead of from the object. (Also `has`.) Slight problem is that you also need to proxy the receiver (not just `base`) in order to handle `ownKeys`. So this could be unworkable.
2. Temporarily get the proxy out of the inheritance chain while setting.

Here's that second one:

```js
var base = {
    foo: function(){
        return "foo";
    }
};

var proxy = new Proxy(base, {
    set: function(target, property, value, receiver){
        const p = Object.getPrototypeOf(receiver); // ***
        Object.setPrototypeOf(receiver, null);     // ***
        receiver[property] = value;                // ***
        Object.setPrototypeOf(receiver, p);        // ***
        return true;
    }
});

var inherited = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(inherited, Object.create(proxy));

inherited.bar = function(){
    return "bar";
};

// Test cases
console.log("base.foo:", base.foo); // function foo
console.log("base.bar:", base.bar); // undefined
console.log("inherited.bar:", inherited.bar); // function bar
console.log("inherited has own bar?", inherited.hasOwnProperty("bar")); // true
```

Comment: Sorry, i thought of another answer using `Object.defineProperty()`. If there weren't that loophole in what the proxy catches, i think your answer would have been the best.

Comment: @blackening: Without doubt, yours is the better way.